# jquery function inside class confusing this keyword

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, this

```
function chat() {
    this.waittime = 6000;
    this.intUpdate = null;

    this.sendChatUpdate = function (msg) {
        var Chatmsg = '0';
        if (msg > 0) {
            Chatmsg = $('#chatmsg');
            var m = Chatmsg.val();
            Chatmsg.val('');
        }

        var s = $("#chatnick").val();
        var r = $("#chatto").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'Chat/ajax/Chat.php',
            data: {
                S: s,
                R: r,
                M: m
            },
            success: function (data) {
                this.ProcessChatReturn(data);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                this.ProcessChatReturn(data);
            }
        });
    }

    this.getUnreadChat = function (mr) {
        var s = $("#chatnick").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'Chat/ajax/Chat.php',
            data: {
                S: s,
                UR: 1,
                MR: mr
            },
            success: function (data) {
                this.ProcessChatReturn(data);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                this.ProcessChatReturn(data);
            }
        });

        //clearTimeout(intUpdate);
        $('#chatbox').show();
    }
}

var chat = new chat();
chat.getUnreadChat();
```

I am getting error "Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'ProcessChatReturn' "

I think it is because if the use of "this" inside of the jquery ajax call.  I want to reference my "chat" object but I think due to including it inside the jquery ajax function it is not.

Any suggestions how to reference my chat object in that location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that because **[this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)** inside the ajax succes callback points to jqXHR object and not to your object context. You can instead cache the object to another variable and use it. There are numerous other ways too.

```
this.sendChatUpdate = function (msg) {
    var Chatmsg = '0';
    if (msg > 0) {
        Chatmsg = $('#chatmsg');
        var m = Chatmsg.val();
        Chatmsg.val('');
    }

    var s = $("#chatnick").val();
    var r = $("#chatto").val(), self = this; //Cache this to self.

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'Chat/ajax/Chat.php',
        data: {
            S: s,
            R: r,
            M: m
        },
        success: function (data) {
            self.ProcessChatReturn(data); //Invoke it with self
        },
        error: function (data) {
            self.ProcessChatReturn(data); //Invoke it with self
        }
    });
}
```

You can also make use of `context` property of ajax settings.

Ex:

```
   $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'Chat/ajax/Chat.php',
        data: {
            S: s,
            R: r,
            M: m
        },
        context:this, //set the context here
        success: function (data) {
            this.ProcessChatReturn(data); //Invoke it with this
        },
        error: function (data) {
            this.ProcessChatReturn(data); //Invoke it with this
        }
    });
```

There are other ways as well like binding the callback function reference using Ecmascript5 [function.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) or [$.proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) , but in your case you can avoid those.

*Note that a context inside a function refers to the context of the caller, or in other words where the function was invoked from **(Except for bound function as mentioned in the last statements)**. In your case you gave a callback to ajax as your anonymous func reference and it gets invoked from jquery ajax object so by default the context points to that*